# Hibernate orm > is it possible to remove some existing column mapping?

Tags: hibernate, orm

I am a newbie of Hibernate. There is a ready class mapping to a table, and the attributes in the class already mapped to different columns of a table by annotations `(@column(name="xxx"))`. This ready class is in a ready JAR, so it is not modifiable. But for some reason I don't need some of the mapped columns at all, thus I would like to override, say removing some unnecessary column mappings. I tried to use ORM XML, say by using the attribute-override elements, but the column element is required in any case, thus I can not achieve the goal of removing some column mapping by means of attribute-override. Is there any other way to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use `JPA`? How you configure your `EntityManagerFactory` or `SessionFactory`?

Comment: Yes, I indeed use JPA, I use ```Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xxx", System.getProperties());```